# Comprehensions that have a binary constructed from a generator

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension

I'm looking through the [comprehension docs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) for elixir, and I'm confused about this snippet:

```
for <<c <- " hello world ">>, c != ?\s, into: "", do: <<c>>
```

specifically, this part: `<<c <- " hello world ">>`

**What is this exactly?** From my understanding `c <- " hello world "` is a generator, and `<<>>` is the binary syntax. So, putting this together it's a binary of a generator? Weird, okay, but perhaps this is similar to python's list comprehension e.g. `[x for x in (1..3)]`

However, it doesn't look like that because the statement cannot stand on its own:

```
iex(2)>  <<c <- " hello world ">>
** (CompileError) iex:2: undefined function <-/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:65: :elixir_bitstring.expand_expr/4
    (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:32: :elixir_bitstring.expand/6
    (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:12: :elixir_bitstring.expand/4
```

If the code can't stand on its own, then how does it work within comprehensions? Is it valid anywhere else outside of comprehensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the syntax Elixir chose to use for binary comprehensions. Erlang on the other hand uses `<=` instead of `<-` for binary comprehensions:

```
% List Comprehension
1> [ X || X <- [1, 2, 3] ].
[1,2,3]
% Binary Comprehension
2> [ X || <<X>> <= <<1, 2, 3>> ].
[1,2,3]
```

> If the code can't stand on its own, then how does it work within comprehensions?

This syntax is valid Elixir code:

```
iex(1)> quote do: <<c <- " hello world ">>
{:<<>>, [], [{:<-, [], [{:c, [], Elixir}, " hello world "]}]}
```

but only the `for` macro uses it as far as I know. `for` is just a macro in Elixir, so you can define your own macros which accept the same syntax.

> Is it valid anywhere else outside of comprehensions?

As far as I know, no.

Comment: Also, it’s probably worth to mention that “the clause might stand by its own” is a very poor way to define the validness, since even the simplest comprehension clause `i <- [1, 2, 3]` cannot stand by its own.